# Stuck with oauth when trying audiomack api

Tags: python, oauth

All I know about API authentication is just password and bearer token. (and NO AUTH too ;)) And I got this OAuth problem when I was trying to use audiomack API.

https://www.audiomack.com/data-api/docs

This is their API documentation. They say

> Rather than manually creating code for OAuth, we recommend instead using one of the pre-built libraries available for your programming language.

And I got piles of python libraries here: [https://oauth.net/1/#:~:text=Max%20Countryman%20maintains,Tornado%20Auth%20package](https://oauth.net/1/#:%7E:text=Max%20Countryman%20maintains,Tornado%20Auth%20package)

Because I am new to OAuth, and also do not know how to get this consumer key and secret from my audiomack account (newly created for test use), these repos give no meaning to me.

Is there anyone who can help me out? I want to know how to make a proper OAuth step to use this API.

A step-by-step guidance or relevant link will be appreciated.